# why dompdf doesn't allow to assign a color to a string?

Tags: php, colors, dompdf

I want to give a color to my string ,but dompdf doesn't allow me. this is my html code :

```
 <style type="text/css">
            .red{
                color:#574595;
            }
         </style>

            <div style="color:#574595;">asdfsdfsd</div><br>
            <font color="red">TRALALAL</font><br>
            <div class="red">TRALALAL</div><br>
```

I tried 3 possible way, but neither don't work. How can I manage that ?
this is my full code :

```
<?php
    ini_set("gd.jpeg_ignore_warning", 1);
    set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . "dompdf");
    require_once('dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php');
    $category = $_GET['c'];
    $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
    $html = 
    '<html>
        <head>
        <style type="text/css">
                    .red{
                        color:#574595;
                    }
                 </style>
        </head>

        <body>


                    <div style="color:#574595;">asdfsdfsd</div><br>
                    <font color="red">TRALALAL</font><br>
                    <div class="red">TRALALAL</div><br>

        </body>
        </html>';
    $dompdf->load_html($html);
    $dompdf->render();

    $output = $dompdf->output();
    file_put_contents("pdf_generated/file.pdf", $output);

    header("Location: http://acros.netlogiq.info/pdf_generated/file.pdf");
?>
```

and this is the result: 
[image]

Comment: is there anyone to help me with this ?

Comment: There are no settings relating to modifying how colors work. Your example should work fine. What version of dompdf are you using? PHP version? Do you get any PHP warnings, notices, or errors (try `ini_set('display_errors',true);` if not)?

Answer (score -1):

Just tried your code here: http://www.digitaljunkies.ca/dompdf/examples.php

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
            .red{
                color:#574595;
            }
         </style>
</head>

<body>


            <div style="color:#574595;">asdfsdfsd</div><br>
            <font color="red">TRALALAL</font><br>
            <div class="red">TRALALAL</div><br>

</body>
</html>
```

And its working, I got red color font. Check your configuration settings once.

EDIT:

DOMPDF PHP CODE:

```
<?php
require_once "../dompdf_config.inc.php";
ini_set("gd.jpeg_ignore_warning", 1);
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
    $html = 
    '<html>
        <head>
        <style type="text/css">
                    .red{
                        color:#574595;
                    }
                 </style>
        </head>

        <body>


                    <div style="color:#574595;">asdfsdfsd</div><br>
                    <font color="red">TRALALAL</font><br>
                    <div class="red">TRALALAL</div><br>

        </body>
        </html>';
    $dompdf->load_html($html);
    $dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("dompdf_out.pdf", array("Attachment" => false));
exit(0);
?>
```

I tried this and I am getting font color. Check your configuration. Configuration UI can be displayed here: localhost/dompdf/www/setup.php

(I hope you have the same folder structure available)

Comment: where can i find my configuration settings ?

Comment: Check my answer again

Comment: i'm getting the same result. Check this :  http://acros.netlogiq.info/pdf_generated/file.pdf    .  What can i change in setup.php ?

Comment: did your tried exactly my code? I mean without redirect just render the PDF in same file with the help of `die()` or `exit()`

Comment: yep . I copy paste it your code and I get the same result

Comment: same thing is coming in your localhost?

Comment: what thing is it comming from my localhost ?

Comment: it weird, because if i write : "<div style="color:#574595;margin-left:100px;">asdfsdfsd</div><br>" the margin-left works but the color not. Why ?

Comment: somethings wrong with your settings. may be some php configuration to render colors, maybe you try to reproduce on your local machine

Answer (score -1):

Check it out this is an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/C6bQf/

Code:

```
<style>
    .red{
        color: red;
}
</style>
<div style="color: red;">asdfsdfsd</div><br>
<font color="red">TRALALAL</font><br>
<div class="red">TRALALAL</div><br>
```

Save your file as HTML.

Comment: Can you send me and screen shoot?, save your file as .html

Comment: please check my post again ! see my full code and the result

Comment: im getting this error : 
Fatal error: Call to undefined method DOMPDF::open_object()